# How can I combine the events "setOnClickListener" and "swipe to the right" or "swipe to the left"?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, events, gesture

I'm new in Android and even newer in Kotlin and I have a problem. I am able to link a LinearLayout with the events "swipe to left" or "swipe to right" and it works properly. But if that LinearLayout contains buttons, then it doesn't work. When the LinearLayout has the buttons the only thing working are the button's "setOnClickListener" but not the "swipe" linked to the LinearLayout. I need both events (onclick and swipe). I share here the code of a little project with this problem. Any help or guide would be appreciated.

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llGeneral"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is the message..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var llGeneral : LinearLayout
    lateinit var llContainer : LinearLayout
    lateinit var button1 : Button
    lateinit var button2 : Button
    lateinit var button3 : Button
    lateinit var message : TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        llGeneral = findViewById(R.id.llGeneral)
        llContainer = findViewById(R.id.llContainer)
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3)
        message = findViewById(R.id.message)


        button1.setOnClickListener {
            message.text = "Button 1 pressed"
        }
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            message.text = "Button 2 pressed"
        }
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            message.text = "Button 3 pressed"
        }


        sweep()

    }


    private fun sweep() {
        llContainer.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(this@MainActivity) {
            override fun onSwipeLeft() {
                super.onSwipeLeft()
                message.text = "Swept to the left..."
            }
            override fun onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight()
                message.text = "Swept to the right..."
            }
            override fun onSwipeUp() {
                super.onSwipeUp()
                message.text = "Swept up..."
            }
            override fun onSwipeDown() {
                super.onSwipeDown()
                message.text = "Swept down..."
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**OnSwipeTouchListener.kt**

```
internal open class OnSwipeTouchListener(c: Context?) :
    OnTouchListener {
    private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
    override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
    }
    private inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD: Int = 100
        private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD: Int = 100
        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            onClick()
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e)
        }
        override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            onDoubleClick()
            return super.onDoubleTap(e)
        }
        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
            onLongClick()
            super.onLongPress(e)
        }


        override fun onFling(
            e1: MotionEvent,
            e2: MotionEvent,
            velocityX: Float,
            velocityY: Float
        ): Boolean {
            try {
                val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
                val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
                if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY)) {
                    if (abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(
                            velocityX
                        ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
                    ) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight()
                        }
                        else {
                            onSwipeLeft()
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(
                            velocityY
                        ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
                    ) {
                        if (diffY < 0) {
                            onSwipeUp()
                        }
                        else {
                            onSwipeDown()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    open fun onSwipeRight() {}
    open fun onSwipeLeft() {}
    open fun onSwipeUp() {}
    open fun onSwipeDown() {}
    private fun onClick() {}
    private fun onDoubleClick() {}
    private fun onLongClick() {}
    init {
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(c, GestureListener())
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `android:focusable="true"` to your `LinearLayout`. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for answer @Izak. Unfortunately it doesn't work. The behaviour is exactly the same. The buttons click works but not the "swipe right or left".

Answer (score 0):

Your llContainer height is only until the last button so there is no area to perform the swipe on, just add the setOnTouchListener on llGeneral OR increase the llContainer height

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This could be a solution and in fact it is. But the problem is I need the "swipe" even when the user do it over the buttons. Imagine a calendar. If you press a day in the calendar you get the date, but if you swipe on any part of the calendar you get the previous or next month. This is the idea.

Comment: Maybe you can remove the click listeners from buttons and add instead touchListener on each button and your touch listener on buttons already have onClick function on it